# get two arrays traversed and generate 2 other arrays by certain conditions

Tags: c#, arrays

I wish to traverse inside 2 arrays in c# and generate 2 separate arrays.
My scenario is like

```
string [] arr = {"1","2","3"};  //can be of different size
 string [] vals = {"a","c,y,z","d"};
 string [] arrArray= new string[] { };
  string [] valArray= new string[] { };
```

I wish to get the arrays arrArray and valArray like

```
arrArray ={"1","2","2","2","3"}
valArray={"a","c","y","z","d"}
```

where in the second positioned string of first array must repeat 3 times because the second array have 3 chars seperated by comma in second position

Comment: have you tried to approach this problem with a oldschool for loop ? [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) is a very helpful method in this case. I also would suggest to use an extendable collection like `List<string>` for `arrArray` and `valArray`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Mong Zhu
I have achieved it

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    
       string[] arr = {"1","2","3"};
       string[] vals = {"a","c,y,z","d"};
       List<string> arrArray= new List<string>();
       List<string> valArr= new List<string>();
       for (int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
       {
       
        if (vals[i].Contains(","))
        {
            string [] innerarray = vals[i].Split(',');
            for (int j = 0; j < innerarray.Length; j++) {
            arrArray.Add(arr[i]);
               valArr.Add(innerarray[j]);
            }
        
         }
        else
        {
            arrArray.Add(arr[i]);
            valArr.Add(vals[i]);
        }
    }
        string [] arwr=arrArray.ToArray();
        string [] arzr=valArr.ToArray();
        foreach(string a in arwr)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine("val");
            foreach(string a in arzr)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```